# CORS - Works locally but API keeps responding browser requests

Tags: node.js, api, cors

I have an API in Node.js that I would like to protect so that it responds only to requests made locally (in development) and by the front-end (React application in production). Below is an example of how I configured it, allowing in the CORS options only requests made by localhost and for my domain (just an example) and it even works. My front-end currently runs on port 3000, and if I change the cors to allow only 3001 for example, due to CORS it blocks access and the back-end doesn't respond to the front-end, which is precisely CORS working and allowing only the accesses of requests coming from the source that I allow, below you can see part of my app.js file, where I configured how CORS should behave

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://meudominio.com.br'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
  }

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Authenticate database connection
connection.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database');
})

// Parsing the application to json
app.use(express.json()) 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// Setting static folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Setting routes
app.use(routes);

// Server listener
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log('The server is running');
})
```

When putting this same code into production my front-end actually has API access, but when I access the API URL directly from the browser, it keeps returning the data in the same way for any user that accesses the URL, which causes CORS doesn't work, since the intention is precisely to allow you to only access the API on localhost and the front-end. Testing locally, when accessing routes through the browser running locally, in the same way, I can access all the data, which I would like to avoid.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as8VZ.png)

I've followed several tutorials from different CORS, tried different shapes and structures but the behavior is always the same, the front-end is allowed to access the API, but any user still has access in the same way through the browser when accessing an API endpoint .

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: CORS stands for _"Cross-Origin Resource Sharing"_. If you're accessing the API directly from the client, it's not cross-origin

Comment: “*CORS doesn't work, since the intention is precisely to allow you to only access the API on localhost and the front-end.*” I don’t agree with this statement at all. I would implore you to re-visit some foundational material on CORS and what it is designed to do and not to do. What you’re trying to do (access an API URL directly in your browser) is not cross-origin (the “CO” in “CORS”), and it’s not clear how you reached a conclusion otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You're understanding CORS incorrectly. CORS is not a lock on the API to work only from certain domains. CORS is a lock on the **browser** to only communicate to an API through a certain domain.

If you're accessing the API from the same URL the API is hosted on, your request is in-fact valid and passes CORS since it's on the same origin!

If you want to lock the API to work from certain domains, you can check the referrer in the headers; however, that can be spoofed!

Best way to lock down an API is keys :)

Comment: _"you're in-fact using CORS"_... don't you mean _not_ using CORS?

Comment: He is though-- it's validating through CORS that's why it goes through. On a browser, you cannot escape CORS unless you download an extension or modify your browser settings heavily!

Comment: But if they are, as you say _"accessing the API from the same URL the API is hosted on"_, then there is only one origin involved so there are no cross-origin requests

Comment: I mean, yeah, you get what I mean here. From a CORS standpoint, the request is valid is what I meant! I will edit my answer to clarify :)

Comment: I think perhaps you too have a slight misunderstanding of what CORS is. It describes a process / set of rules that a resource owner (server / API) can implement to allow browsers to circumvent the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and request resources from another domain (origin). If there's only one origin involved or the client is not a browser, there is simply no CORS

Comment: CORS is always in effect! 100% of the time. When you're using same domain, it does not apply to CORS yes, but CORS is still in effect.

Comment: Gotta disagree with you there. How can _cross-origin resource sharing_ be in effect when a request is same-origin?

Comment: It does not apply to this particular request because it's the same origin. But it's still in effect on the browser as a whole-- I think what we're disagreeing on is philosophical rather than technical, lol

Comment: I think you're confusing CORS with some kind of check that browsers perform regarding request origins for XHR. I still upvoted 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238631/discussion-between-david-harvey-and-phil).